# Confusion on Error State Kalman Filter reset

Tags: kalman-filters, imu, ekf

I have been reading about kalman filters for IMU and I am confused on the error state formulation.

Reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf), starting on page 63 and going onto 64 the paper addresses the reset of the error state.

[image: Error Reset]

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf

My confusion is what is meant by line 284? 285 just looks like it sets the error state to zero and 286 is applying a linear transformation to the error state covariance, but I don't understand what function is really being used in 284 for the quaternion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My confusion is what is meant by line 284?

In section 4 of the paper they define the $\oplus$.  Then they define $\ominus$ as being the inverse: i.e., if $a = b \oplus c$, then $c = a \ominus b$.

They left out the time index, and you need to peer closely to see that they'e distinguishing $\delta \mathbf x$ (the error state) from $\hat {\delta \mathbf x}$ (the *estimate* of the error state, with a hat).

Adding indexes, that's
$$\delta \mathbf x_k \leftarrow g(\delta \mathbf x_{k-1}) = \delta \mathbf x_{k-1} - \hat {\delta \mathbf x}_{k-1} \tag {284-update}$$

> 285 just looks like it sets the error state to zero

(285) sets the *estimated* error state to zero -- again, note the hat.  The *actual* error state is, formally, unknown, being the difference between the *actual* state of the system (whatever that is) and your *estimate* of the actual state.

Comment: I think I am following but in this case quaternions are used with multiplication. I am confused on the G matrix still, I understand it's the jacobian but I still don't really follow. I understand it gets into some niche lie theory.

Comment: When you read section 4 of the paper -- the one that addresses your confusion -- which bits didn't you understand?  Perhaps you should _edit your question_ with those bits, and how they confuse you.

Comment: Reviewing this basically, you need to recenter the error state system. You apply another linearization to update the covariance matrix for the reset operation. Simply setting the error vector to zero doesn't update the covariance matrix.